# PDO/MySQL: Inserting with a prepared statement - 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

I am writing a simple database application with PHP and MySQL. I am using ajax to run scripts server-side. I have written a database class using PDO.

I have written various php scripts to handle inserting data, and they're all using my class's "prepare()" and "execute()" methods.

I wrote a separate php script to create the tables and delete the tables, and also to insert sample data, and to delete all data. This is to help me return to a "known" set of data while I am building and debugging the database application.

I have created four buttons in html, and I am calling a php script asychronously, passing a variable called "script" using GET. In my script, I have a switch statement which determines the SQL command to run. There are no variables I need to bind.

When I click a button to execute a script, it works - if the circumstances allow. So, for example, if I click to delete all tables, it will delete the tables. However, if I click it again (and there are no tables there to delete), the javascript returns a 500 - Internal Server Error. I would like to return an error message, but can't work out where in my scripts to handle this.

Here are my class methods:

```
public function prepare($query){
  // PDO prepare allows for binding of values, removes threat of SQL injection and improves query performance
  $this->statement = $this->connection->prepare($query);
}

public function bind($parameter, $value, $type = null){
  // PDO bindValue binds inputs to placeholders
  if(is_null($type)){
    switch(true){
      case is_int($value):
        $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
        break;
      case is_bool($value):
        $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
        break;
      case is_null($value):
        $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
        break;
      default:
        $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
    }
  }
  $this->statement->bindValue($parameter, $value, $type);
}

public function execute(){
  // Executes the prepared statement
  return $this->statement->execute();
}

public function allresults(){
  // Returns all results
  $this->execute();
  return $this->statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

And here is the key part of the php script being called with ajax:

```
switch ($script) {
  case "create":
      global $create_tables;
      global $database;
      $database->prepare($create_tables);
      $result = $database->execute($create_tables);
      if($result){
        echo "Success";
      }
      else{
        echo "Failed";
      }
      break;
```

One of the buttons:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="library('newsql.php?script=create')">Create Tables</button>
```

And my js:

```
function library(path) {


xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET",path,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
};
```

I think it has something to do with the standard return for a prepared statement, but maybe it's something to do with executing a prepared statement without binding variables, or repeating a prepared statement without changing variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a problem of diagnosing what is going on.

- In your JS function, you're handling status == 200 but nothing for errors (like 500)
- Open your development console at the browser (F12) and go to "Network" tab before you click the button to get the 500 error, you'll be able to see the headers and response tabs for your ajax call (the request/response Headers AND the html/json/whatever Response) that is your PHP
- Being a 500 error at PHP and you see nothing at the Response, then your PHP script is not echoing nothing, but you'll probably see something at your error log for PHP OR Apache. You have to learn to monitor those at each call when an error 500 arise. Then you'll see the exact reason you're obtaining an error 500 for your call instead of the 200 (OK) you're expecting at your JS function...

Hope that helps.

Comment: That helps. I checked my php error log, and noticed that since I wasn't doing anything to catch exceptions on my PDO execute method, it was not behaving as expected. I've amended my method with a try-catch and it's returning the correct error message now, instead of an internal sever error. Thanks for your help.